# Addressing the problem of symmetry in metric space based representations of words in computational linguistics

Tags: computational-linguistics

In the field of computational linguistics it's very common to represent words / sentences/ etc as mathematical objects and then use said representations to elicit certain linguistic tasks. The most common that I've observed in the research domain is Weighed Di-Graphs, Discrete Probability Distributions, and High Dimensional Vectors (often sparse) that exist in a Metric Space that operates over the field of Real Numbers.

In the case of Metric Spaces, it has been well documented in a number of papers that for certain tasks the axioms associated with the use of metric spaces presents concerns; namely symmetry and triangle inequality axioms. In attempting to begin with the simpler of two (as I perceive it) being symmetry, I'm curious as to whether this has been relaxed and alternative algebraic structures have been employed? (say a Lie-Algebra). I am unable to find anything within the standard research outlets but am hoping that I may have missed an article.

I fear that my question here may not have the required detail. If it doesn't please comment and advise where I can expand and improve.

Edit - 
Thought I would add a specific examples as a means of illustration. Consider you are processing a book word by word, let's say that at word i you have the word 'a' - from that, what if you wanted to find the probability of encountering word 'b' in the next 'n' words. This in general is different to having the word 'b' at position 'i' and finding the probability of encountering word 'a' in the next 'n' words. As a direct example, let a = 'dog', b = 'pet', and n = 100 then if we observed 'dog' there is far greater likelihood that we will encounter 'pet' in  the next 100 words than if we had 'pet' to then have 'dog' in the next 100 words. So the probability of 'dog' to 'pet' here is potentially very different to the relationship of 'pet' to 'dog'. Thus we have an asymmetrical state in the relationship between the words.

Comment: I know nothing about Lie-Algebra, but as for the scenario you described, have you looked into Bayesian networks or Markov process?

Comment: I am afraid, that the core of this question is mathematical rather than linguistic. Mathematicians always think of releasing some axioms and creating more abstract algebraic structures, so there are certainly types of spaces without symmetry and without triangular equations (Minkowski space highly relevant in physics is an example of the latter type). For a non-symmetric measure of distance actually employed in linguistic research, consider Kullback Leibler Divergence (KLD).

Comment: I'm not an expert, but my understanding is that NLP uses a vector of real numbers not because they need a Euclidean metric space, but because modern computers are really, really efficient at rapidly processing vectors of real numbers.  The efficiency is so high that it's counterintuitive: you could have a different algorithm with a hundred times less computation, but if the computation is serial, it could easily run *slower* than vector computation running in a modern GPU.

Comment: @jknappen - It is very much a maths question, but it's hinged on it's authenticity in it's linguistic application. Yes, I'm very familiar with the KL Divergence but there are a number of inherent assumptions forced onto it's use - the most prominent being that the representation is a discrete probability distribution. I was hoping to find an examination (even if from a very introductory manner) as to how higher order tensor spaces  / alternative vector spaces under a new type of 'distance' could account and/or assisting in non symmetric relationships.

Comment: @jick - Do you have any supporting documentation for that claim? and by processing what are you referring to? 

If it's to compute distance than 'Real' based vectors (in general) present the greatest mathematical efficiency. And they have served incredibly well, however I believe they fall short in their ability to explain non 'Real' behaviour in Algebraic Structures.  

But it's a field still very much in it's infancy in relations to marrying mathematics to linguistics.

Comment: Sorry I can't find a reference now... (I'm an amateur myself), but I heard many times the sentiment that attempts at mathematically elegant models were defeated by advances in brutal computational power - basically, you are not as good as finding patterns as you think, so don't try, and let the machines find patterns for you.

Comment: Regarding your second question, "processing" means anything. For example, to answer your asymmetrical example ("is a dog a pet?"), modern ML will simply create a neural network with two word vectors as input, and a score as output.  In a sense it's deeply unsatisfying because it's just another black box, but it works really well in practice.

Comment: @jick - Yes, I've heard the ML/DNN is able to examine patterns in incredible ways. Ironically however they are based on mathematical models. The greater majority of Machine Learning is essentially Linear & Non-Linear Regression modelling. Deep Neural Networks are effectively multiple layered Weighted Di-Graphs. 

I'm currently resisting 'giving up' on my current focus in using Defined Algebraic Structures... but I am losing hope. Even if it has a significant place, at this point, it would be isolating and without cross fertilisation of other researchers.

Comment: @jick I agree with the sentiments as far as applied NLP goes, but addressing the asymmetry issue may be important for pure linguistic research. (Note that I say may; in practice the problems caused may be minimal, e.g. I don't see people complaining about the use of (non-pointwise) mutual information for collocation extraction even though it doesn't distinguish between attraction and repellence. But that doesn't mean we can always get away with symmetry.)

Comment: @WavesWashSands - In my experience there is a lot deliberate ignorance. Symmetry is a significant one, but I'm generally more concerned about vector vector representations constructed in the first orthant

Comment: *solely in the first orthant